# Custom project DXF data with metre units in JavaScript

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, autocad, proj4js

I have a GeoJSON file with coordinates in metres in what I believe is the AutoCad World Coordinate System. (I converted from the DXF that was supplied to me, which was exported from AutoCad). The scale of the file is roughly 2x2 kilometres.

I need to place it on a map. I would like to make use of the fact that the coordinates are in metres during the projection process, to avoid distorting it.

Let's assume I know the lat/long where (0, 0) should be placed, and perhaps a rotation angle. How can I then translate these X/Y coordinates to EPSG:4326?

I need to do this in the browser, using JavaScript.

Is there a straightforward way to generate a Proj4 (hence Proj4JS) string given this information? Or some other approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer may be along these lines:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=<LAT> +lon_0=<LON> +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

Where `<LAT>` and `<LON>` are the location to set the origin.